# Temporary store git credentials in credential-cache

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, carthage

I have run into some authentication trouble with **Carthage**, GitLab CI and our internal dependencies. 
Our runners are clean and do not have any credentials for GitLab stored in their keychain for security reasons.

When `carthage bootstrap` is run in a job, Carthage uses `git credential fill` to authenticate a request and in our case it fails.

```
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git fetch --prune --quiet https://gitlab.corp.com/path/to/lib.git refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* (launched in /Users/x/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/lib)) failed with exit code 128:
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
remote: You must use a personal access token with 'api' scope for Git over HTTP.
remote: You can generate one at https://gitlab.corp.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.corp.com/path/to/lib.git/'
```

Every job gets a job token and it should use that to communicate with GitLab.

How do I temporarily insert username `gitlab-ci-token` and password `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` into the git credential-cache store?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I temporarily insert username gitlab-ci-token and password $CI_JOB_TOKEN into the git credential-cache store?

That would suggest the `gitlab.corp.com` URL is already associated with a username/password right now in the Windows Credential Manager (used by the git credential helper).

Since a credential manager can only associate *one* credential to one URL, you might need to switch to an SSH scheme, where you won't have the token restriction.
That can even be done automatically, with a:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@gitlab.corp.com/.insteadOf https://gitlab.corp.com/
```

Comment: Hi @VonC https is the only option for me and the CI runner must remain clean. Also running on macOS.